# How to count different card combinations with isomorphism?

Tags: combinatorics

Let's consider a standard deck of cards and say that two sets of cards are isomorphic if there exists permutation of colors that makes one set into another.

For example: `A♡ K♡ K♧` is isomorphic with `A♤ K♤ K♡`, but not than `A♢ K♤ K♧`

Now we can count that there are 1326 different pair of cards, but when considering the color isomorphisms there are only 169 of them.

Is there a generic formula or approach to calculate it for any problem size (number of ranks(AKQ..), colors(♢♡♧♤...), and set size?

Comment: How much do you know about combinatorics?

Comment: How did you get those numbers? I think there are $\frac 12 52\cdot 51$ pairs of cards and only $13\cdot 12+13\cdot 13$ pairs of cards up to color-isomorphisms.

Comment: I know very little about combinatorics. there 1/2 * 52 * 51 == 1326. 169 comes from 13*13.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We have a set of colors $C$ and a set of numbers $N$.  We [act on](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Group_action) $C \times N$ by the [symmetric group](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symmetric_group) $\mathrm{Sym}(C)$, with $(c,n) \overset{\alpha}{\mapsto} (\alpha(c),n)$ for all $\alpha \in \mathrm{Sym}(C)$ and $(c,n) \in C \times N$.  This induces an action on the set of $k$-subsets of $C \times N$.

The number of isomorphism classes is given by [Burnside's Lemma](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Burnside%27s_lemma).  In this case, if $\alpha,\beta \in \mathrm{Sym}(C)$ have the same cycle structure, then $\alpha$ and $\beta$ stabilize the same number of elements in $C \times N$.

So the number or isomorphism classes is $$\frac{1}{|C|!} \sum_{\text{partitions $P$ of |C|}} \text{nr permutations with cycle structure } P \times |\mathrm{Stab}(\rho)|$$ where $\rho$ denotes a representative permutation with cycle structure $P$.  Here $\mathrm{Stab}(\rho)$ is the set of $k$-subsets of $C \times N$ which are fixed by acting on them with $\rho$.

The number of permutations with a given cycle structure is $$\frac{|C|!}{\prod_{i \geq 1} s(i)!\ i^{s(i)} }$$ where $s(i)$ is the number of $i$-cycles in the cycle structure.

Calculating $|\mathrm{Stab}(\rho)|$ is trickier.  It might be that any formula for $|\mathrm{Stab}(\rho)|$ is essentially "compute $|\mathrm{Stab}(\rho)|$" in disguise.  If the color $b$ belongs to a $t$-cycle in $\rho$, then we either have all of $(b,n),(\rho(b),n),\ldots,(\rho^{t-1}(b),n)$ in the $k$-subset, or we have none of these.

In the $C=\{1,2,3,4\}$, $N=\{1,2,\ldots,13\}$, and $k=2$ case, we have these representative permutations:

- $\mathrm{id}$: This fixes everything, so $|\mathrm{Stab}(\mathrm{id})|=\binom{4 \times 13}{2}=1326$.
- $(12)$: We fix any subset that doesn't have the color $1$ or $2$, of which there are $\binom{2 \times 13}{2}=325$, and if the subset has $(c,n)$ where $c \in \{1,2\}$ then it has both $(1,n)$ and $(2,n)$, giving $13$ more possibilities.  So $|\mathrm{Stab}(12)|=338$.
- $(12)(34)$: Similar the above case, we either have $\{(1,n),(2,n)\}$ or $\{(3,n),(4,n)\}$, so we have $|\mathrm{Stab}(12)(34)|=26$.
- $(123)$: We can't use the colors $1$, $2$ or $3$, otherwise $(1,n)$, $(2,n)$, and $(3,n)$ would be in our $2$-subset, giving a contradiction, so the subset is $\{(4,n),(4,n')\}$ for two distinct $n,n' \in N$.  So $|\mathrm{Stab}(12)|=\binom{13}{2}=78$.
- $(1234)$: Similar to the above case, we have $|\mathrm{Stab}(1234)|=0$.

Hence the number of isomorphism classes is $$\frac{1}{4!}(1 \times 1326+6 \times 338+3 \times 26+8 \times 78+6 \times 0)=169.$$

(I don't think this number "comes from" $13 \times 13$ though.)

Comment: It comes from 13x13 in a sense that all 2 card isomorphism classes could be written on a square like this: pairs (AA/KK/QQ) on a diagonal. Different suit on upper side of a diagonal and same suits on lower side of the diagonal. This square is 13x13 and every isomorphic class has its place. That wouldn't be possible with sets of 3 cards or more though.

Answer (score 5):

In this post we will show  how to compute the number of non-isomorphic
$k$-subsets for all $k$  where $0\le k\le 52.$ What we  have here is a
**Power  Group Enumeration**  problem (in  the  sense of  the term  as
described   by  Harary   in  *Graphical   Enumeration*  and   also  by
Fripertinger  in  *Enumeration in  Musical  Theory*),  with the  group
acting on  the slots where  the cards  are placed being  the symmetric
group $S_N$  on $N$ elements and  the group acting on  the cards being
the permutation  group $Q$  with $24$  elements obtained  by permuting
suits / colors.

For the cycle  index $Z(Q)$ observe that since  suit permutation never
changes the values of the cards we have that cards with the same value
replicate the cycle structure of the  cycles from $Z(S_4)$ that act on
the four  suits.  This means the  cycles from the latter  are repeated
$13$ times, once for each face value, and we get

$$Z(Q) = \left.Z(S_4)\right|_{a_1=a_1^{13}, a_2=a_2^{13},
a_3=a_3^{13}, a_4=a_4^{13}}$$

which is
$$Z(Q) = 1/24\,{a_{{1}}}^{52}+1/4\,{a_{{1}}}^{26}{a_{{2}}}^{13}
+1/3\,{a_{{1}}}^{13}{a_{{3}}}^{13}
+1/8\,{a_{{2}}}^{26}+1/4\,{a_{{4}}}^{13}.$$

We can  compute the number  of configurations / subsets  by Burnside's
lemma which  says to average  the number  of assignments fixed  by the
elements of the  power group, which has $4!\times  |S_N|$ elements and
$|S_N|=N!$.  But  this number is easy  to compute.  Suppose we  have a
permutation $\alpha$  from $S_N$ and  a permutation $\beta$  from $Q$.
If  we  place  the  appropriate   number  of  complete,  directed  and
consecutive copies  of a cycle from  $\beta$ on a cycle  from $\alpha$
then this assignment  is fixed under the power group  action, and this
is  possible iff  the length  of the  cycle from  $\beta$ divides  the
length of the cycle from $\alpha$ and there are as many assignments as
the  length  of  the  cycle  from  $\beta$.   There  is  an  important
observation to make here, however.  We are only interested in sets and
not in  multisets. That  means we  cannot place  multiple copies  of a
cycle from $\beta$  on a cycle from $\alpha$ as  we would be repeating
elements. Therefore the problem for pairs $(\alpha, \beta)$ reduces to
computing the  number of subsets  of cycles  from $\beta$ that  we can
place in  their entirety  on the  cycles of $\alpha$  to cover  all of
$\alpha.$ Hence  the multiset of  cycle lengths  of $\beta$ must  be a
superset of  the cycle lengths  from $\alpha$, containing at  least as
many cycles of length $k$ as $\alpha$ plus possibly some other cycles.
It is therefore sufficient  to  iterate over the variables that appear
in $\alpha,$ checking  that they are present in $\beta$  with the same
or higher  degree and  choosing cycles  from the  latter to  cover the
former. There is a multiplicative factor  to account for the fact that
the number of ways  of covering a cycle is given by  the length of the
cycle that does the covering.

Now the  Burnside computation  is best  done with a  CAS, here  is the
Maple code.  Note that it suffices  to work with the  cycle indices of
the two groups which is  lower complexity than iterating over all $N!$
permutations of $S_N.$

```
with(combinat);
with(numtheory);

pet_cycleind_symm :=
proc(n)
option remember;

    if n=0 then return 1; fi;

    expand(1/n*add(a[l]*pet_cycleind_symm(n-l), l=1..n));
end;


pet_cycleind_cards :=
proc()
    option remember;
    subs([seq(a[q]=a[q]^13, q=1..4)],
         pet_cycleind_symm(4));
end;

q :=
proc(N)
option remember;
local idx_slots, idx_cards, res, term_a, term_b,
    v_a, inst_a, inst_b, len_a, p;

    if N = 0 then return 1 fi;

    if N = 1 then
        idx_slots := [a[1]];
    else
        idx_slots := pet_cycleind_symm(N);
    fi;

    idx_cards := pet_cycleind_cards();

    res := 0;

    for term_a in idx_slots do
        for term_b in idx_cards do
            p := 1;

            for v_a in indets(term_a) do
                len_a := op(1, v_a);
                inst_a := degree(term_a, v_a);
                inst_b := degree(term_b, v_a);

                if inst_b >= inst_a then
                    p := p*binomial(inst_b, inst_a)
                    *inst_a!*len_a^inst_a;
                else
                    p := 0;
                    break;
                fi;
            od;

            res := res +
            lcoeff(term_a)*lcoeff(term_b)*p;
        od;
    od;

    res;
end;
```

The above yields  the complete list of the  nonisomorphic subset count
for the standard deck which  is (observe that these can definitely not
be computed by brute force and note the symmetry as well):
$$1,13,169,1755,16432,134459,962988,6009159,32819436,\\
157702259,671225412,2546958349,8668626707,26607292908,\\
74002375408,187274148048,432761029519,915980606957,\\
1780453974039,3185285527359,5254786194372,8006264748053,\\
11280519244644,14712774203725,17777183437949,19909964116172,\\
20675571474936,19909964116172,17777183437949,14712774203725,\\
11280519244644,8006264748053,5254786194372,3185285527359,\\
1780453974039,915980606957,432761029519,187274148048,\\
74002375408,26607292908,8668626707,2546958349,671225412,\\
157702259,32819436,6009159,962988,134459,16432,1755,169,13,1.$$

Answer (score 0):

Once we have the Z(Q) we can apply the differential operator

$$ \frac {1} {2} \frac{\partial ^2 Z}{\partial a_1^2} + \frac{\partial Z}{\partial a_2}$$

and the resulting $Z^{x,x}(Q)$ is the cycle index of the combinatorial species obtained after the removal of a pair of cards among the 52.

$$Z^{x,x}(Q) = {221 \over 4} a_1^{50} + 
{325 \over 4}  a_1^{24} a_2^{13} + 
{13 \over 4}  a_1^{26} a_2^{12} + 
26 . a_1^{11} a_3^{13} +
{13 \over 4} a_2^{25} $$

The number of types is given by the sum of coefficients above,

$$169 = {221 \over 4}  + {325 \over 4}  + {13 \over 4}  + 26 + {13 \over 4} $$

I found mentions of differential operators as far as N.G. de Bruijn, 1964, Applied Combinatorial Mathematics, editor Edwin Beckenbach, multiple authors.