# Stirling numbers and Power Group Enumeration

Tags: group-theory, reference-request, generating-functions, stirling-numbers

The following question is  a **reference request** concerning a derivation
of the EGF for the Stirling numbers of the second kind by Power
Group Enumeration / Burnside's Lemma, which is
$$\sum_{n\ge 0} {n\brace k} \frac{z^n}{n!}
= \frac{(\exp(z)-1)^k}{k!}.$$

The idea  is very  simple. The labelled  set partitions  that Stirling
numbers count can  be represented by placing one of  $k$ colors into a
row of $n$ adjacent slots, where  $n$ is the set being partitioned and
$k$ gives the number of components. Hence a color signals what set the
value corresponding to the slot should belong to.

The value of ${n\brace k}$ is then given by the number of orbits under
the power  group action  obtained by letting  the group acting  on the
slots  be the  identity and  the  group acting  on the  colors be  the
symmetric group  on $k$ elements  $S_k.$ Now applying Burnside  we see
that the group acting on  the slots consists of one element containing
$n$ fixed  points.  The admissible  assignments to these  fixed points
under a  permutation $\beta$ acting on  the colors are  those that are
fixed  points of  $\beta.$ If  we have  $q$ such  fixed points  we can
obtain  $q^n$  valid  assignments  to  the slots  under  the  identity
permutation.

We thus require  the cycle index of the  symmetric group $Z(S_k)$ with
the fixed points marked. Recall that the OGF of these cycle indices is
obtained from the combinatorial class 
$$\def\textsc#1{\dosc#1\csod}
\def\dosc#1#2\csod{{\rm #1{\small #2}}}
\textsc{SET}(\mathcal{A_1}\times\textsc{CYC}_1(\mathcal{W})
+ \mathcal{A_2}\times\textsc{CYC}_2(\mathcal{W})
+ \mathcal{A_3}\times\textsc{CYC}_3(\mathcal{W}) 
+ \cdots)$$
which gives
$$\exp\left(a_1 w + a_2 \frac{w^2}{2} + a_3 \frac{w^3}{3} + \cdots 
\right).$$
Keeping only the marker on the fixed points we obtain
$$G(w, v)
= \exp\left(v w + \frac{w^2}{2} + \frac{w^3}{3} + \cdots\right)
\\ = \exp\left(v w - w + \log\frac{1}{1-w}\right)
= \frac{e^{-w}}{1-w} e^{vw}.$$

We  now  determine  the  transformation required  of  this  generating
function. A  term $C v^q w^m$  must be transformed into  $C q^n w^m.$
This gives
$$\left.\left(v\frac{d}{dv}\right)^n G(w, v) \right|_{v=1}.$$

Observe however that  this term is a generating  function of colorings
where the term  $w^k$ indexes colorings of *at  most* $k$ colors. That
means we  actually require the difference between  the coefficients on
$w^k$ and on $w^{k-1}.$ This finally yields the formula

$${n\brace k} = 
[w^k] (1-w) \left.\left(v\frac{d}{dv}\right)^n G(w, v) \right|_{v=1}.$$

Substituting the actual value of $G(w, v)$ and moving constants to the
front we obtain
$${n\brace k} = [w^k] e^{-w}
\left.\left(v\frac{d}{dv}\right)^n e^{vw} \right|_{v=1}.$$

Introduce the generating function
$$P(z) = \sum_{n\ge 0} {n\brace k} \frac{z^n}{n!}
= [w^k] e^{-w}
\left.\sum_{n\ge 0} \frac{z^n}{n!} 
\left(v\frac{d}{dv}\right)^n e^{vw} \right|_{v=1}.$$
Now the operator represented by the sum turns $v^q w^m$ into
$$\left(1 + \frac{zq}{1!} 
+ \frac{(zq)^2}{2!}
+ \frac{(zq)^3}{3!}
+ \cdots\right) \times v^q \times w^m
= e^{zq} \times v^q \times w^m.$$

This yields for $P(z)$ that
$${\large P(z) = [w^k] e^{-w}
\left. e^{\exp(z)\times v \times w}\right|_{v=1}}
\\= {\large [w^k] e^{-w} e^{\exp(z) w}
= [w^k] e^{(\exp(z)-1) w}.}$$
So that finally
$$\color{#A00}{P(z)= \frac{(\exp(z)-1)^k}{k!}}.$$
This concludes the proof.

The purpose of  this post is to determine as  **precise a reference as
possible**  for this  proof, taking  into account  all aspects  of the
technique used. If a precedent with an exact match could be found that
would be terrific.

**Post Scriptum.** There is an instructive example of Power Group Enumeration at this
[MSE link](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/864116/how-to-count-different-card-combinations-with-isomorphism).