# Getting the proof of the generating function formula for Stirling numbers by 'staring' at the expression using combinatorial classes.

Tags: combinatorics, generating-functions

In his lectures on enumerative combinatorics, Prof. Federico Ardila gives a [homework](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7SauUKXbfFw&list=PL-XzhVrXIVeSi7xym1XAfFIxOAaHVhjtP&feature=player_detailpage#t=2302). For a fixed natural $k$, he asks us to prove the identity:

$$\sum_{n \geq 0} S(n,k) z^n = \left(\frac{z}{1-z}\right)\left(\frac{z}{1-2z}\right)...\left(\frac{z}{1-kz}\right).$$

Here, $S(n,k)$ is the number of ways of partitioning a $n$-element set into $k$ sets.

I know the proof of the above identity using recursions. I also know combinatorial proofs of related identities. But I want to know the proof using combinatorial classes.

It looks like the combinatorial class of $k$-partitions is the product of the classes Seq({$0,1,2,...,l$}) from $l=0$ to $l=k-1$. But I am unable to find an such an interpretation.

How do I solve this problem?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

The difficulty here  is that you have an OGF  where most commonly EGFs
are  used. Nonetheless a  proof using  unlabeled species  and advanced
Polya Enumeration can be given.

Some time  ago I posted  an intriguing result  proving the EGF  of the
Stirling numbers ${n\brace k}$ with  $k$ fixed which seems not to have
found an audience. This is the
[MSE link](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/921102/).

We  can  use  the  material from  this  link  without  explicitly
recapitulating everything  as it is  sound. The following  formula was
proved there by methods of species theory (unlabeled):
$${n\brace k} = [w^k] e^{-w}
\left.\left(v\frac{d}{dv}\right)^n e^{vw} \right|_{v=1}.$$

Introduce the generating function
$$P(z) = \sum_{n\ge 0} {n\brace k} z^n
= [w^k] e^{-w}
\left.\sum_{n\ge 0} z^n
\left(v\frac{d}{dv}\right)^n e^{vw} \right|_{v=1}.$$
Now the operator represented by the sum turns $v^q w^m$ into
$$\left(1 + (zq)
+ (zq)^2
+ (zq)^3
+ \cdots\right) \times v^q \times w^m
= \frac{1}{1-qz} \times v^q \times w^m.$$

Therefore $$e^{vw} = \sum_{q\ge 0} \frac{v^q w^q}{q!}$$ is transformed
into $$\sum_{q\ge 0} \frac{1}{1-qz} \frac{v^q w^q}{q!}.$$

This yields for $P(z)$ that
$$P(z) = [w^k] e^{-w}
\left. \sum_{q\ge 0} \frac{1}{1-qz} \frac{v^q w^q}{q!} \right|_{v=1}
= [w^k] e^{-w}
\sum_{q\ge 0} \frac{1}{1-qz} \frac{w^q}{q!}.$$

Actually doing the coefficient extraction we obtain
$$P(z) = \sum_{p=0}^k \frac{(-1)^{k-p}}{(k-p)!} 
\frac{1}{1-pz} \frac{1}{p!}
= \frac{1}{k!} \sum_{p=0}^k {k\choose p} \frac{(-1)^{k-p}}{1-pz}.$$

Now to see that this is equal to 
$$Q(z) = \prod_{p=1}^k \frac{z}{1-pz}$$
we can use partial fractions by residues for rational functions,
getting
$$\mathrm{Res}_{z=1/m} Q(z)
= \mathrm{Res}_{z=1/m} \frac{z/m}{1/m-z}
\prod_{p=1}^{m-1} \frac{z}{1-pz}
\prod_{p=m+1}^k \frac{z}{1-pz}
\\ = -\frac{1}{m^2}
\prod_{p=1}^{m-1} \frac{1/m}{1-p/m}
\prod_{p=m+1}^k \frac{1/m}{1-p/m}
\\ = -\frac{1}{m^2}
\prod_{p=1}^{m-1} \frac{1}{m-p}
\prod_{p=m+1}^k \frac{1}{m-p}
= -\frac{1}{m^2} \frac{1}{(m-1)!} \frac{(-1)^{k-m}}{(k-m)!}
\\ = -\frac{1}{m} \frac{1}{m!} \frac{(-1)^{k-m}}{(k-m)!}.$$

On the other hand
$$\mathrm{Res}_{z=1/m} P(z)
= \mathrm{Res}_{z=1/m} 
\frac{1}{k!} {k\choose m} \frac{(-1)^{k-m}}{1-mz}
\\ = - \frac{1}{m} \mathrm{Res}_{z=1/m} 
\frac{1}{k!} {k\choose m} \frac{(-1)^{k-m}}{z-1/m}
= -\frac{1}{m} \frac{1}{m!} \frac{(-1)^{k-m}}{(k-m)!}.$$

The residues  are equal, all the  poles are simple,  the two functions
are rational  and have  no other poles,  hence we have  equality. This
concludes the proof.