# Stirling numbers: Combinatorial proof of an identity

Tags: combinatorics, stirling-numbers

How to prove the following combinatorially ?

\begin{equation}
{n+1 \brace k+1}=\sum_{m=k}^{n}(k+1)^{n-m}{m \brace k}.
\end{equation}

My question is how are only ( n - m ) elements being considered to be placed on the (k + 1) boxes ? And that too without any combination like n **C** (n - m) ?

Answer (score 2):

Suppose that you have a distribution of the set $\{1,\ldots,n+1\}$ into $k+1$ identical boxes. Let $m$ be the smallest number such that the set $\{1,\ldots,m\}\cup\{n+1\}$ contains an element of every box. In other words, $m$ is the smallest number such that $\{1,\ldots,m\}$ contains an element of each of the $k$ boxes *not* containing $n+1$. Clearly $k\le m\le n$. How many distributions share this number $m$?

- There are ${m\brace k}$ ways to distribute the numbers $1,\ldots,m$ amongst the $k$ boxes not containing $n+1$.
- The The $n-m$ elements of $\{m+1,\ldots,n\}$ can then be distributed arbitrarily amongst the $k+1$ boxes in $(k+1)^{n-m}$ ways.

Thus, there are a total of $(k+1)^{n-m}{m\brace k}$ distributions of $\{1,\ldots,n+1\}$ into $k+1$ identical boxes that share this value of $m$, and hence

$$\sum_{m=k}^n(k+1)^{n-m}{m\brace k}$$

distributions altogether.

Comment: thx for that nice explanation, Brian. i had the basic idea, but didn't find your neat way of convincing myself that double-counting was ruled out.

Comment: @David: You’re welcome.

Comment: Brian, thanks for taking the time to reply. You said, "There are {mk} ways to distribute the numbers 1,…,m amongst the k boxes not containing n+1." 

What I don't get is why don't we choose all combinations of this selection of k from n ? Why a seemingly arbitrary selection of k objects ? Shouldn't it be something like $$\binom{n}{k} * {m \brace k}$$ ?

Comment: @Guest123: We aren’t selecting $k$ things. We have $m$ things, where $m$ is the smallest integer such that the first $m$ things use all $k$ of the boxes not containing the $(n+1)$-st thing, and we’re counting the ways to distribute them amongst $k$ boxes.

Comment: Prof. Brian thanks again. Actually that's what I wanted to clarify as to WHY aren't we selecting those m things. It seems arbitrary. We can have any combination of these m things, so somewhere it IS indeed being taken care of. I'll try to find out how it is so. Thank you.

Comment: @Guest123: It comes out of how we’re dividing the distributions into categories. For each distribution there is a unique integer $m$ such that items $1$ through $m-1$ together $n+1$ leave some box empty, while items $1$ through $m$ together with $n+1$ leave no box empty. That $m$ must be between $k$ and $n$ inclusive. Each term of the summation counts the distributions with one value of $m$. We know that for such a distribution items $1$ through $m$ can be in any of the ${m\brace k}$ possible distributions requiring $k$ boxes, and the other $n-m$ items (not counting item $n+1$, which is in ...

Comment: @BrianM.Scott Your last comment above is not formatted properly. Please remove and repost. I would like to ask if we are not doing any double counting here. For example doesn't ${m\brace k}$ with $m=k+3$ for example include those distributions where $m=k+1.$?

Comment: ... the $(k+1)$-st box) can be distributed amongst the $k+1$ boxes in any way at all. There are $(k+1)^{n-m}$ ways to do that, for a grand total of $(k+1)^{n-m}{m\brace k}$ distributions having this value of $m$. What we’re counting here simply doesn’t involve selecting $k$ objects; it depends only on the number $m$, which is uniquely determined for each possible distribution.

Comment: @Marko: No, $m$ is uniquely determined by the distribution: it’s the *smallest* integer such that $\{1,\ldots,m\}\cup\{n+1\}$ require all $k+1$ boxes.

Comment: Prof. Brian, that was my doubt too. For a given m, I could have multiple distributions like say, **{** 1,2,3, **(** 4,5 **)** **}** **OR** **{** 2,3,5, **(** 1,4 **)** **}**. In both cases, m is 3, even though the distributions are NOT identical. That's why I'd asked, shouldn't there also be a combination term multiplying (m+1)^(n-k) and {m n} within the summation sign ? I'll re-read all your comments to understand this further. Thank you for your time.

Comment: @Guest123: Yes, there are lots of distributions with the same $m$: $(k+1)^{n-m}{m\brace k}$ of them. What prevents double counting is the fact that each distribution has only one value of $m$ associated with it.

Comment: Well, that m is the same for many distributions as we can see. So why don't we multiply by a combination term to account for all of them ? (here I differ from Marko. Earlier I thought he was asking the same thing).

Comment: @Guest123: Because they aren’t counted by any binomial coefficient. The factors $(k+1)^{n-m}$ and ${m\brace k}$ account for them, as explained in both the answer and the comments.

Answer (score 0):

By way of enrichment here is a proof using generating functions.
Suppose we seek to evaluate
$$\sum_{m=k}^n (k+1)^{n-m} {m\brace k}
= (k+1)^n \sum_{m=k}^n (k+1)^{-m} {m\brace k}.$$

This is
$$(k+1)^n \sum_{m=0}^{n-k} (k+1)^{-m-k} {m+k\brace k}$$
or
$$(k+1)^{n-k} \sum_{m=0}^{n-k} (k+1)^{-m} {m+k\brace k}.$$

What we have here is
$$(k+1)^{n-k} [z^{n-k}] \frac{1}{1-z}
\sum_{m\ge 0} {m+k\brace k} \frac{z^m}{(k+1)^m}.$$

Now recall the OGF of Stirling numbers with fixed $k$
which was evaluated e.g. at this
[MSE link](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1134671/):
$$P(z) = \sum_{m\ge 0}{m\brace k} z^m
= \prod_{p=1}^k \frac{z}{1-pz}.$$
This is
$$\sum_{m\ge k}{m\brace k} z^m
= \sum_{m\ge 0}{m+k\brace k} z^{m+k}.$$
It follows that
$$\sum_{m\ge 0}{m+k\brace k} z^{m}
= \prod_{p=1}^k \frac{1}{1-pz}.$$

Substituting this into the sum yields
$$(k+1)^{n-k} [z^{n-k}] \frac{1}{1-z}
\prod_{p=1}^k \frac{1}{1-pz/(k+1)}
\\ = (k+1)^{n-k} [z^{n-k}]
\prod_{p=1}^{k+1} \frac{1}{1-pz/(k+1)}
\\ = (k+1)^{n-k} [z^{n-k}] 
\prod_{p=1}^{k+1} \frac{k+1}{k+1-pz}
\\ = (k+1)^{n+1} [z^{n-k}] 
\prod_{p=1}^{k+1} \frac{1}{k+1-pz}.$$

This is
$$\frac{(k+1)^{n+1}}{2\pi i}
\int_{|z|=\epsilon} \frac{1}{z^{n-k+1}}
\prod_{p=1}^{k+1} \frac{1}{k+1-pz} \; dz.$$

Put $z=(k+1) w$ so that $dz = (k+1)\; dw$ to get
$$\frac{(k+1)^{n+1}}{2\pi i}
\int_{|w|=\epsilon} \frac{k+1}{w^{n-k+1}(k+1)^{n-k+1}}
\prod_{p=1}^{k+1} \frac{1}{k+1-p(k+1)w} \; dw$$
which is
$$\frac{1}{2\pi i}
\int_{|w|=\epsilon} \frac{k+1}{w^{n-k+1}(k+1)^{-k}}
\prod_{p=1}^{k+1} \frac{1}{k+1-p(k+1)w} \; dw
\\ = \frac{1}{2\pi i}
\int_{|w|=\epsilon} \frac{1}{w^{n-k+1}(k+1)^{-(k+1)}}
\prod_{p=1}^{k+1} \frac{1}{k+1-p(k+1)w} \; dw
\\ = \frac{1}{2\pi i}
\int_{|w|=\epsilon} \frac{1}{w^{n-k+1}}
\prod_{p=1}^{k+1} \frac{1}{1-pw} \; dw
\\ = \frac{1}{2\pi i}
\int_{|w|=\epsilon} \frac{w^{k+1}}{w^{n+2}}
\prod_{p=1}^{k+1} \frac{1}{1-pw} \; dw
\\ = \frac{1}{2\pi i}
\int_{|w|=\epsilon} \frac{1}{w^{n+2}}
\prod_{p=1}^{k+1} \frac{w}{1-pw} \; dw.$$

This last integral evaluates to
$${n+1\brace k+1}$$
by inspection.

Comment: Marko, that is some proof ! Though I don't understand it, I'm sure it'll be useful for someone looking for a non-combinatorial proof. Actually I was seeking a combinatorial proof.

Comment: I was aware of that but I posted anyway for variety's sake.

Comment: @Guest123 It appears that the proof by Brian M. Scott is not difficult and rewards detailed examination.