# Richard Pavlicek's combinatorial problem

Tags: combinatorics, closed-form

In the game of bridge, a standard deck is dealt to four players, 13 cards each. That gives a total of $\binom{52}{13,13,13,13}$ distinct deals.

How many distinct deals can be dealt if all spot cards - $2$ through $9$ - are considered equal in rank (but retain their suits.)

This question originates on [Richard Pavlicek's bridge site](http://www.rpbridge.net/7z74.htm).

He asks a combinatorial question. I am also interested in a solution
but unfortunately, I have no plan how the formula can be constructed.

Can anyone help ?

Comment: You could at least state the problem yourself.

Comment: @Peter Done. It was odd to see Pavlicek's name on a math site. I'm so used to seeing his name on bridge sites.

Comment: @thomas if you are a bridge freak, you might be interested in this question : http://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/23788/par-zero-deal-with-many-points-for-n-s

Comment: I think I invented the phrase "par zero deal," actually. @Peter At least, I hadn't seen it anywhere before I wrote up a list of them. If you google "Par Zero Deal" my collection is the first thing that comes up.

Comment: @thomas Did you collect some more par-zero deals ? If yes, you might create a site with all par-zero-deals you know. I am very interested in this topic and I would like to see surprising or even crazy par-zero-deals.

Comment: It's already there. http://bridge.thomasoandrews.com/deals/parzero/

Comment: @thomas In Richard Pavliceks database, there are 25 par-zero deals and I found some more with a double dummy solver and richard pavliceks deal creator. Do you know a double dummy solver that can search automatically for par-zero-deals ? You mentioned such a solver but I could not install it. A win.zip-file would be nice.

Comment: I already studied your site, good job!

Comment: Do you remember which was the highest sum of HCP for N/S (or E/W) ?

Comment: @Thomas: Wow, those are fascinating!

Comment: Thanks, @BrianTung. My bridge site is written from my math nerd point of view, so it is ideal for mathematically-inclined bridge players.

Comment: I resemble that comment!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This problem can  be solved by the Polya  Enumeration Theorem.  Ignore
the  no spot  cards for  the moment  as they  only  contribute trivial
symmetries.  The  setup here  is that we  have $8\times 4$  slots into
which we  distribute assignments to  players $A,B,C$ and $D.$  We have
the symmetric group $S_8$ acting on  each block of spot cards from the
same suit. This gives the cycle index $$Z(Q) =Z(S_8)^4.$$

It follows that the number of deals where player $A$ receives $a$ spot 
cards, player $B$ receives $b$ spot cards and so on is given by
$$[A^a B^b C^c D^d] Z(S_8)^4(A+B+C+D).$$

If  all four  degrees are  at  most thirteen  we can  combine such  an
assignment with  an assigment  of the no  spot cards of  the remaining
cards,  which is  given by  a  simple multinomial  coefficient, for  a
contribution of 
$${20\choose 13-a,13-b,13-c,13-d} 
[A^a B^b C^c D^d] Z(S_8)^4(A+B+C+D).$$
It remains to sum these terms from $Z(Q)$ to get the answer, which is
$$800827437699287808.$$

Observe that all of these terms have $a+b+c+d=32.$
Note also  that the multinomial  corresponds to multiplying  $Z(Q)$ by
$a_1^{20},$  representing twenty fixed  points for  the no  spot cards
which are not being permuted.

Here the computation features the recurrence by Lovasz  for the cycle  index $Z(S_n)$, which is
$$Z(S_n) = \frac{1}{n} \sum_{l=1}^n a_l Z(S_{n-l})
\quad\text{where}\quad
Z(S_0) = 1.$$

This was the Maple code that I used.

```
with(combinat);
with(numtheory);


pet_cycleind_symm :=
proc(n)
local p, s;
option remember;

    if n=0 then return 1; fi;

    expand(1/n*add(a[l]*pet_cycleind_symm(n-l), l=1..n));
end;

pet_cycleind_idspots := pet_cycleind_symm(8)^4;

pet_varinto_cind :=
proc(poly, ind)
local subs1, subs2, polyvars, indvars, v, pot, res;

    res := ind;

    polyvars := indets(poly);
    indvars := indets(ind);

    for v in indvars do
        pot := op(1, v);

        subs1 :=
        [seq(polyvars[k]=polyvars[k]^pot,
             k=1..nops(polyvars))];

        subs2 := [v=subs(subs1, poly)];

        res := subs(subs2, res);
    od;

    res;
end;

count :=
proc()
option remember;
    local sind, res, term, Ad, Bd, Cd, Dd;

    sind := pet_varinto_cind(A+B+C+D, pet_cycleind_idspots);
    res := 0;

    for term in expand(sind) do
        Ad := degree(term, A);
        Bd := degree(term, B);
        Cd := degree(term, C);
        Dd := degree(term, D);

        if Ad<=13 and Bd<=13 and Cd<=13 and Dd<= 13 then
            res := res + term/A^Ad/B^Bd/C^Cd/D^Dd*
            20!/(13-Ad)!/(13-Bd)!/(13-Cd)!/(13-Dd)!;
        fi;
    od;

    res;
end;
```

The output of the Maple program is as follows. 
The timing here was less than one tenth of a second.

```
> count();
memory used=37195.2MB, alloc=8.3MB, time=436.90
memory used=37197.7MB, alloc=8.3MB, time=436.94
                                  800827437699287808
```

This matches the value presented at the linked web site.

A somewhat more advanced computation involving suits being distributed is at this  [MSE link](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/864116).

Comment: It would be neat to see what this algorithm we could get with all cards except the ace and king treated as equal, so we could possibly test it.

Comment: If I have not made a mistake (which is unfortunately not that unlikely) the answer I get is $$630343600320,$$ which it seems is still beyond reach of brute force enumeration.

Comment: Well, there are steps between brute force and your algorithm. :)

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out, I should have reflected on my choice of terms here before commenting.  In fact the algorithm on the linked web page should not be difficult to adapt to this new scenario.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it can be helped, and the name is Bruijn (1964),

$P_H({\partial\over\partial z_1},{\partial\over\partial z_2}, {\partial\over\partial z_3},...)  P_G (z_1, 2z_2,3z_3,...)$

the terminology saying the *incomplete delabeling*.

Following Bruijn, $P_H$ and $P_G$ are cycles indexes.

I will show the minimal example, by supposing that bridge is a game of two players, North and South, played with Aces, 9's and 8's of two colors, spade and heart.

Then $P_G$ is the cycle index of the species $Ens_3.Ens_3$ or the action of $S_6$ over hands (triplets of cards)

$P_G =  {1\over 3!} (z_1^3 + 3z_1z_2 + 2z_3) . {1\over 3!} (z_1^3 + 3z_1z_2 + 2z_3)$

$P_H$  describes the system of labels to be applied in this one-to-one mapping context.
AS (the ace of spade) and AH are fixed. 9S and 8S can swapped and also 9H and 8H. Then

$P_H = z_1^2{z_1^2+z_2 \over 2!}{z_1^2+z_2 \over 2!}$

After differentiation by Bruijn formula, the result is $10$, the number of patterns within respect with the original terminology.

Here are the ten hands

AS, AH, h

AS, AH, s

AS, h, h

AS, h, s

AS, s, s

AH, h, h

AH, h, s

AH, s, s

h, h, s

s, s, h