# Number of unique hex tiles with two paths on each edge?

Tags: combinatorics, combinations

I want to know:

How many "unique" hexagonal tiles can be created with two paths exiting on each edge?

There will always be only 6 paths (connecting two different exits) per tile.

Note: No duplicate tiles. Meaning, if you were to rotate the tile in any orientation it would not be the same as another.

Comment: Are the left path and the right path on any one edge distinct? (that is, if I switch the path links on one edge, is that a different tile?

Comment: Please clarify, perhaps with several pictures. Can paths cross? Can a path join the two exits on one side? Do reflections count as symmetries? Are two paths that exit on the same side but at different exits different?

Answer (score 2):

This problem is a case of  **Power Group Enumeration** in the sense of
the paper by Fripertinger which was discussed quite extensively at the
following [MSE link](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/864116/).
The set of values consists of the possible edges and is being permuted
by the rotations of the  hexagon, call this $G$. Edges are represented
by products $A_p A_q$ where $p$  and $q$ range from zero to eleven and
correspond to  a clockwise enumeration of  the exits and  there are no
edges between  adjacent exits (same edge).   This is a  feature of the
problem which  is open to debate  and which I hope  I have interpreted
correctly.   The slots  are simply  six  slots being  permuted by  the
symmetric group  $S_6.$ The  technique is exactly  the same as  at the
quoted link -- note that we seek sets of edges and not multisets which
simplifies  things  considerably.  In  a  nutshell  we consider  pairs
$(\beta,\alpha)$ of  permutations from  the edge permutations  $G$ and
the  symmetric group $S_6$  and compute  the generating  function that
corresponding to  all possible ways  of covering $\alpha$  with cycles
from $\beta.$  At the  end we extract  those terms that  contain every
exit exactly once. A remarkable feature of this problem is that we are
working  with generating  functions here  but the  generating function
that appears when  we try to cover $a_1^6$  with cycles (fixed points)
from  $a_1^{60}$ produces  a completely  unmanageable number  of terms
which  it is impossible  to process.  Fortunately the  contribution of
this term  can be computed  in closed form.  It has no  symmetries and
simply  counts all  tiles before  symmetry. As  we must  exclude edges
between adjacent exits we get by inclusion-exclusion

$$\bbox[5px,border:2px solid #00A000]{
\sum_{k=0}^6 {6\choose k} (-1)^k \frac{(12-2k)!}{2^{6-k} (6-k)!}
= 6040.}$$

We  simply wire  this value  into  the program  and detect  $a_1^{60}$
during  the **Power Group  Enumeration** computation.  This is  all we
need to be aware of at this time and the answer is

$$\bbox[5px,border:2px solid #00A000]{1060.}$$

The  reader is  invited to  verify  this result  by classifying  tiles
according  to their  symmetries and  counting the  number of  tiles in
every class.

I also verfied this by a  total enumeration routine which in fact does
not  require  all  that much  time  /  space  and confirms  the  above
findings. PGE obviously generalizes while simple enumeration does not.

This was the Maple code.

```
with(combinat);

pet_autom2cyclesA :=
proc(src, aut)
local numa, numsubs, marks, pos, cycs,
    data, item, cpos, clen;

    numsubs := [seq(src[k]=k, k=1..nops(src))];
    numa := subs(numsubs, aut);

    marks := Array([seq(true, pos=1..nops(aut))]);

    cycs := []; pos := 1; data := [];

    while pos <= nops(aut) do
        if marks[pos] then
            clen := 0; item := []; cpos := pos;

            while marks[cpos] do
                marks[cpos] := false;
                item := [op(item), aut[cpos]];

                cpos := numa[cpos];
                clen := clen+1;
            od;

            cycs := [op(cycs), clen];
            data := [op(data), item];
        fi;

        pos := pos+1;
    od;

    return [data, mul(a[cycs[k]], k=1..nops(cycs))];
end;


pet_cycleind_symm :=
proc(n)
local p, s;
option remember;

    if n=0 then return 1; fi;

    expand(1/n*add(a[l]*pet_cycleind_symm(n-l), l=1..n));
end;


edges_all_src :=
proc()
option remember;
local edges;

    edges :=
    add(add(A[p]*A[q], q=p+1..11), p=0..11)
    - add(A[2*p]*A[2*p+1], p=0..5);

    [seq(p, p in edges)];
end;

pet_perms_edge_cind :=
proc()
option remember;
local cind, p, q, perm, sl,
    edges, edgeperm, rotind;

    edges := edges_all_src();

    cind := [];

    for rotind from 0 to 5 do
        sl :=
        [seq(A[p]=A[(p+2*rotind) mod 12], p=0..11)];
        edgeperm := subs(sl, edges);

        cind :=
        [op(cind), pet_autom2cyclesA(edges, edgeperm)];
    od;

    cind;
end;

tiles :=
proc()
option remember;
local slot_idx, edge_idx, gf, var, flat, cycs,
    edge_term, slot_term, contrib, cover, deg, onesize;

    slot_idx := pet_cycleind_symm(6);
    edge_idx := pet_perms_edge_cind();

    gf := 0;

    for slot_term in slot_idx do
        for edge_term in edge_idx do
            if edge_term[2] = a[1]^60 then
                next;
            fi;

            if type(edge_term[2]/slot_term,
                    `monomial`) then
                contrib := 1;

                for var in indets(slot_term) do
                    cycs :=
                    select(c->nops(c)=op(1,var),
                           edge_term[1]);

                    onesize := 0;
                    deg := degree(slot_term, var);

                    for cover in choose(cycs, deg) do
                        onesize := onesize
                        + deg!*op(1,var)^deg*
                        mul(mul(el, el in cyc),
                            cyc in cover);
                    od;

                    contrib := contrib*onesize;
                od;

                gf := gf + lcoeff(slot_term)*contrib;
            fi;
        od;
    od;

    gf := expand(gf);

    for var from 0 to 11 do
        gf := coeff(gf, A[var], 1);
    od;

    (gf + 6040)/6;
end;

enum_all_symm :=
proc()
option remember;
local recurse, count, edges, orbits;

    edges := edges_all_src();
    orbits := table();

    recurse :=
    proc(sofar, sel, n, pos)
    local orbit, sl, rotind;

        if n = 6 then
            count := count + 1;

            orbit := {};

            for rotind from 0 to 5 do
                sl :=
                [seq(A[p]=A[p+2*rotind mod 12],
                     p=0..11)];

                orbit :=
                {op(orbit), subs(sl, sel)};
            od;

            orbits[orbit] := 1;

            return;
        fi;

        if pos > nops(edges) then
            return;
        fi;

        recurse(sofar, sel, n, pos+1);

        if nops(indets(sofar*edges[pos])) =
        2*(n+1) then
            recurse(sofar*edges[pos],
                    {op(sel), edges[pos]},
                    n+1, pos+1);
        fi;
    end;

    count := 0;
    recurse(1, {}, 0, 1);

    [count, nops([indices(orbits)])];
end;
```

**Addendum  Mon  Jun  26  2017.**  Presenting  a  completely  reworked
algorithm  and implementation,  which  gives an  instant answer.   The
previous  version  computed  the  entire generating  function  in  the
variables representing  the exits,  expanding intermediate  terms even
including those that  did not contribute. As  indicated this algorithm
breaks  down  when  placing  cycles  corresponding  to  $a_1^{60}$  on
$a_1^6.$ The new version uses

$$[z^k] \prod_{q\in C} (1+zq)$$

to represent a choice of $k$ cycles  from a set of cycles $C$ and does
not  expand  this  term,  which   means  that  the  contribution  from
$a_1^{60}$ only consists of $60$  terms as opposed to ${60\choose 6},$
which is not feasible. We thus get a product of these (times a leading
coefficient)  when there  exists a  covering of  the slot  permutation
$\alpha$ by cycles from the edge permutation $\beta,$ where $k$ is the
number of cycles of a given size in $\alpha$ and $C$ are the cycles of
that size from $\beta,$ which is not a conjugacy class in this problem
but  an  actual permutation  of  the  edges. Having  constructed  this
product we differentiate with respect to all variables in sequence and
set  them to  zero thereafter,  which isolates  the contribution  from
those  terms  where  each  exit  occurs just  once.   We  extract  the
coefficients that  correspond to the  desired power of $[z^k]$  at the
very end,  producing a  number which gives  the possible  coverings of
$\alpha$  by cycles  from  $\beta$  that contribute  to  the count  of
admissible  tiles. The  Maple  code was  as  follows (the  enumeration
routine has  also been improved.)  We omit  the prefix that  is shared
with the first version.

```
tiles :=
proc()
option remember;
local slot_idx, edge_idx, slot_term, edge_term,
    cycs, deg, gf, var, res;

    slot_idx := pet_cycleind_symm(6);
    edge_idx := pet_perms_edge_cind();

    res := 0;

    for slot_term in slot_idx do
        for edge_term in edge_idx do
            if type(edge_term[2]/slot_term,
                    `monomial`) then
                gf := 1;

                for var in indets(slot_term) do
                    cycs :=
                    select(c->nops(c)=op(1,var),
                           edge_term[1]);

                    deg := degree(slot_term, var);

                    gf := gf*deg!*op(1, var)^deg
                    *mul(1+z[op(1, var)]*mul(el, el in cyc),
                         cyc in cycs);
                od;

                for var from 0 to 11 do
                    gf :=
                    subs(A[var] = 0, diff(gf, A[var]));
                od;

                for var in indets(slot_term) do
                    gf :=
                    coeftayl(gf, z[op(1, var)]=0,
                             degree(slot_term, var));
                od;

                res := res + lcoeff(slot_term)*gf;
            fi;
        od;
    od;

    res/nops(edge_idx);
end;

enum_all_tiles :=
proc()
option remember;
local recurse, count, edges, orbits, sl;

    edges := edges_all_src();
    orbits := table();

    sl :=
    [seq([seq(A[p]=A[p+2*r mod 12], p=0..11)],
         r=1..5)];

    recurse :=
    proc(sofar, sel, n, pos)
    local orbit, rotind;

        if n = 6 then
            count := count + 1;

            orbit := [sel];

            for rotind to 5 do
                orbit :=
                [op(orbit),
                 subs(sl[rotind], sel)];
            od;

            orbits[sort(orbit)[1]] := 1;

            return;
        fi;

        if pos > nops(edges) then
            return;
        fi;

        recurse(sofar, sel, n, pos+1);

        if nops(indets(sofar*edges[pos])) =
        2*(n+1) then
            recurse(sofar*edges[pos],
                    {op(sel), edges[pos]},
                    n+1, pos+1);
        fi;
    end;

    count := 0;
    recurse(1, {}, 0, 1);

    [count, numelems(orbits)];
end;
```

**Addendum  Wed  Jun 28  2017.**  We  present  the case  of  arbitrary
polygonal  tiles  having  $q$  sides rather  than  hexagonal  ones  to
complete this discussion and end on a challenge to the reader.  We get
by inclusion-exclusion for the count with no symmetries the formula

$$\bbox[5px,border:2px solid #00A000]{
\sum_{k=0}^q {q\choose k} (-1)^k \frac{(2q-2k)!}{2^{q-k} (q-k)!}.}$$

Here we choose  the $k$ spots where there is  an edge between adjacent
exits (which we are wanting to avoid), for a factor of ${q\choose k}.$
This leaves  $2q-2k$ exits. We choose  two of these  to  connect by an
edge, then another two from the  remaining exits, and another two, and
so on, for a multinomial coefficient ${2q-2k\choose 2,2,\ldots,2}.$
Here  we may  choose one  set  of edges  in $(q-k)!$  ways, hence  the
formula. We obtain the sequence starting at $q=1$:

$$0, 2, 8, 60, 544, 6040, 79008, 1190672, 20314880, 387099936,\ldots$$

Taking symmetries into account yields the following sequence:

$$0, 2, 4, 22, 112, 1060, 11292, 149448, 2257288, 38720728\ldots$$

and  the  challenge  to  the  reader is  of  course  to  compute  more
terms for the latter. This is the Maple code:

```
edges_all_src :=
proc(q)
option remember;
local edges;

    edges :=
    add(add(A[p]*A[r], r=p+1..2*q-1), p=0..2*q-1)
    - add(A[2*p]*A[2*p+1], p=0..q-1);

    [seq(p, p in edges)];
end;

pet_perms_edge_cind :=
proc(q)
option remember;
local cind, perm, sl,
    edges, edgeperm, rotind;

    edges := edges_all_src(q);

    cind := [];

    for rotind from 0 to q-1 do
        sl :=
        [seq(A[p]=A[(p+2*rotind) mod 2*q], p=0..2*q-1)];
        edgeperm := subs(sl, edges);

        cind :=
        [op(cind), pet_autom2cyclesA(edges, edgeperm)];
    od;

    cind;
end;

tiles :=
proc(q)
option remember;
local slot_idx, edge_idx, slot_term, edge_term,
    cycs, deg, gf, var, res;

    slot_idx := `if`(q=1, [a[1]], pet_cycleind_symm(q));
    edge_idx := pet_perms_edge_cind(q);

    res := 0;

    for slot_term in slot_idx do
        for edge_term in edge_idx do
            if type(edge_term[2]/slot_term,
                    `monomial`) then
                gf := 1;

                for var in indets(slot_term) do
                    cycs :=
                    select(c->nops(c)=op(1,var),
                           edge_term[1]);

                    deg := degree(slot_term, var);

                    gf := gf*deg!*op(1, var)^deg
                    *mul(1+z[op(1, var)]*mul(el, el in cyc),
                         cyc in cycs);
                od;

                for var from 0 to 2*q-1 do
                    gf :=
                    subs(A[var] = 0, diff(gf, A[var]));
                od;

                for var in indets(slot_term) do
                    gf :=
                    coeftayl(gf, z[op(1, var)]=0,
                             degree(slot_term, var));
                od;

                res := res + lcoeff(slot_term)*gf;
            fi;
        od;
    od;

    res/nops(edge_idx);
end;

tiles_all :=
q -> add(binomial(q,k)*(-1)^k*(2*q-2*k)!/2^(q-k)/(q-k)!,
         k = 0..q);

enum_tiles_all :=
proc(q)
option remember;
local recurse, count, edges, orbits, sl;

    edges := edges_all_src(q);
    orbits := table();

    sl :=
    [seq([seq(A[p]=A[p+2*r mod 2*q], p=0..2*q-1)],
         r=1..q-1)];

    recurse :=
    proc(sofar, sel, n, pos)
    local orbit, rotind;

        if n = q then
            count := count + 1;

            orbit := [sel];

            for rotind to q-1 do
                orbit :=
                [op(orbit),
                 subs(sl[rotind], sel)];
            od;

            orbits[sort(orbit)[1]] := 1;

            return;
        fi;

        if pos > nops(edges) then
            return;
        fi;

        recurse(sofar, sel, n, pos+1);

        if nops(indets(sofar*edges[pos])) =
        2*(n+1) then
            recurse(sofar*edges[pos],
                    {op(sel), edges[pos]},
                    n+1, pos+1);
        fi;
    end;

    count := 0;
    recurse(1, {}, 0, 1);

    [count, numelems(orbits)];
end;
```

**Addendum Fri Jun  30 2017.** The data for  dihedral symmetries being
taken into account (rotational and reflectional) are as follows:

$$0, 2, 4, 19, 80, 638, 6054, 76692, 1137284, 19405244,\ldots $$

**Addendum Mon Jul  3 2017.** It appears that plain  Burnside is still
the best approach.  This requires that  we compute the number of tiles
fixed by each of the $q$ rotations including the identity, which fixes
all tiles. These are counted  by the inclusion-exclusion formula given
above. For the remaining rotations we  have that they must be constant
on the  cycles (obtained by factorizing  the corresponding permutation
of edges). This means that to be  fixed by a given rotation a cycle of
edges is either switched on or  off (all edges simultaneously). We use
a backtracking search to determine which  cycles may be switched on at
the same time  without creating conflict (more than  one edge incident
on  the same  exit.)  This  lets us  calculate three  more values  for
rotational symmetries and we obtain

$$0, 2, 4, 22, 112, 1060, 11292, 149448, 2257288, 38720728, 
\\ 740754220, 15648468804, 361711410384, \ldots$$

We also  find that we  have effectively  solved the problem  for tiles
whose  number of  sides is  a prime.  We find  (more of  these can  be
computed)

$$2, 4, 112, 11292, 740754220, 361711410384, 222595582448849152,
\\ 258327454310582805036, 661821993709898403923269564, 
\\ 10266982973657640119698928948136690256,\ldots$$

The Maple code for this goes as follows.

```
with(combinat);

pet_autom2cyclesA :=
proc(src, aut)
local numa, numsubs, marks, pos, cycs,
    data, item, cpos, clen;

    numsubs := [seq(src[k]=k, k=1..nops(src))];
    numa := subs(numsubs, aut);

    marks := Array([seq(true, pos=1..nops(aut))]);

    cycs := []; pos := 1; data := [];

    while pos <= nops(aut) do
        if marks[pos] then
            clen := 0; item := []; cpos := pos;

            while marks[cpos] do
                marks[cpos] := false;
                item := [op(item), aut[cpos]];

                cpos := numa[cpos];
                clen := clen+1;
            od;

            cycs := [op(cycs), clen];
            data := [op(data), item];
        fi;

        pos := pos+1;
    od;

    return [data, mul(a[cycs[k]], k=1..nops(cycs))];
end;


edges_all_src :=
proc(q)
option remember;
local edges;

    edges :=
    add(add(A[p]*A[r], r=p+1..2*q-1), p=0..2*q-1)
    - add(A[2*p]*A[2*p+1], p=0..q-1);

    [seq(p, p in edges)];
end;

tiles_no_symm :=
q -> add(binomial(q,k)*(-1)^k
         *(2*q-2*k)!/2^(q-k)/(q-k)!, k=0..q);

bs_tiles :=
proc(q)
option remember;
local res, sl, recurse, edgecycs, cind, vsets,
    edges, edgeperm, rotind, seen, factored;

    edges := edges_all_src(q);

    res := tiles_no_symm(q);

    recurse :=
    proc(cycs, sofar, pos)
    local data, nxt;

        if nops(sofar) = 2*q then
            return 1
        fi;

        if pos > nops(cycs) then
            return 0
        fi;

        data := recurse(cycs, sofar, pos+1);

        if nops(cycs[pos] intersect sofar) = 0 then
            data := data +
            recurse(cycs, cycs[pos] union sofar, pos+1);
        fi;

        return data;
    end;

    cind := [];

    seen := table(); 
    for rotind to q-1 do
        sl :=
        [seq(A[p]=A[(p+2*rotind) mod 2*q], p=0..2*q-1)];

        edgeperm := subs(sl, edges);

        cind :=
        [op(cind),
         pet_autom2cyclesA(edges, edgeperm)];
    od;

    for factored in cind do
        if not(type(seen[factored[2]], `integer`)) then
            vsets :=
            map(indets,
                select(cf -> { seq(degree(cf, v), v in indets(cf)) }
                       = { 1 },
                       map(cyc -> mul(el, el in cyc), factored[1])));

            seen[factored[2]] := recurse(vsets, {}, 1);
        fi;

        res := res + seen[factored[2]];
    od;

    res/q;
end;
```

With  Burnside we  also get  three more  terms for  dihedral symmetry,
which yields

$$ 0, 2, 4, 19, 80, 638, 6054, 76692, 1137284, 19405244, 
\\ 370597430, 7825459362, 180862277352,\ldots$$

The reason  why the above code  for cyclic symmetry is  structured the
way  it is  becomes  apparent  when we  study  the  code for  dihedral
symmetry,  which  is  why  I  decided to  present  it  here,  omitting
duplicate code.

```
edges_all_src :=
proc(q)
option remember;
local edges;

    edges :=
    add(add(C[p]*C[r], r=p+1..2*q-1), p=0..2*q-1)
    - add(C[2*p]*C[2*p+1], p=0..q-1);

    subs([seq(C[2*p]=A[p], p=0..q-1),
          seq(C[2*p+1]=B[p], p=0..q-1)],
         [seq(p, p in edges)]);
end;

tiles_no_symm :=
q -> add(binomial(q,k)*(-1)^k
         *(2*q-2*k)!/2^(q-k)/(q-k)!, k=0..q);

bs_tiles_dh :=
proc(q)
local res, sl, recurse, cind, vsets,
    edges, edgeperm, rotind, seen, factored;

    edges := edges_all_src(q);

    res := tiles_no_symm(q);

    recurse :=
    proc(cycs, sofar, pos)
    local data, nxt;

        if nops(sofar) = 2*q then
            return 1
        fi;

        if pos > nops(cycs) then
            return 0
        fi;

        data := recurse(cycs, sofar, pos+1);

        if nops(cycs[pos] intersect sofar) = 0 then
            data := data +
            recurse(cycs, cycs[pos] union sofar, pos+1);
        fi;

        return data;
    end;

    cind := [];

    seen := table();
    for rotind from 0 to q-1 do
        if rotind >= 1 then
            sl :=
            [seq(A[p]=A[(p+rotind) mod q], p=0..q-1),
             seq(B[p]=B[(p+rotind) mod q], p=0..q-1)];

            edgeperm := subs(sl, edges);

            cind :=
            [op(cind),
             pet_autom2cyclesA(edges, edgeperm)];
        fi;

        sl :=
        [seq(A[p]=B[q-1-((p+rotind) mod q)], p=0..q-1),
         seq(B[p]=A[q-1-((p+rotind) mod q)], p=0..q-1)];

        edgeperm := subs(sl, edges);

        cind :=
        [op(cind),
         pet_autom2cyclesA(edges, edgeperm)];
    od;

    for factored in cind do
        if not(type(seen[factored[2]], `integer`)) then
            vsets :=
            map(indets,
                select(cf -> { seq(degree(cf, v), v in indets(cf)) }
                       = { 1 },
                       map(cyc -> mul(el, el in cyc), factored[1])));

            seen[factored[2]] := recurse(vsets, {}, 1);
        fi;

        res := res + seen[factored[2]];
    od;

    res/q/2;
end;
```

Answer (score 1):

If the paths cannot cross, there are a rather limited number of tiles under the constraints given; I make it 5:

[image: tile 1]
[image: tile 2]
[image: tile 3]
[image: tile 4]
[image: tile 5]

Comment: Jordan, crossing paths is accepted. And, what did you use to create those images?

Comment: @ErikMiller Those images were made in Powerpoint, which has a nice "save as picture" option.